# Difficulties trying to include TinyMCE to a template

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-templates

After successfully intergrating TinyMCE in my template with a valid API key, i experience difficulties with publishing the content written on the textarea. The issues is that the content gets published with HTML tags. when you type 'Hello World' on the textarea and publish, this is what you get "<p>**Hello World !**</p>" How can i get rid of the HTML tags and remain with clean content 'Hello World' ?

I have tried cleaning the content using the Bleach library;
`post.text = Cleaner().clean(post.text)`

tried to strip off the tags using an if statment as well;

```
{% if post.content %}
   {{ post.content|striptags }}
 {% endif %}
```